# In XSD, how to define a type which contains several occurences of a subtype, one with restriction

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Can someone tell me, whether it is possible to define a type which can contain several elements of a complex subtype. However,

1. It must contain at least one child.
2. For this child, the value of a grandchild is restricted to one specific value.
3. For the optional other children, the value of the grandchild is restricted to a set of string values.

Example:

```
<Identifiers>
<ns:Identifier xmlns:ns='http://schemas.com/common'>
    <ns0:SourceSystem xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.com/common'>ORACLE</ns0:SourceSystem>
    <ns0:IDType xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.com/common'>PARTY_ID</ns0:IDType>
    <ns0:IDValue xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.com/common'>38784313</ns0:IDValue>
</ns:Identifier>
<ns:Identifier xmlns:ns='http://schemas.com/common'>
    <ns0:SourceSystem xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.com/common'>ORACLE</ns0:SourceSystem>
    <ns0:IDType xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.com/common'>ANY_ID</ns0:IDType>
    <ns0:IDValue xmlns:ns0='http://schemas.com/common'>12345</ns0:IDValue>
</ns:Identifier>
```

The first occurance of the Identifier element has the mandatory value "PARTY_ID" for IDType. The second occurance is optional and can have any value from the enumeration.

Here are some extracts from the current XSD in which there is no restriction for the number of Identifier elements.

```
<xsd:complexType name="IdentifiersType">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Identifier" type="cmn:IdentifierType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

```
<xsd:complexType name="IdentifierType">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="SourceSystem"/>
    <xsd:element ref="cmn:IDType"/>
    <xsd:element name="IDValue" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

```
<xsd:simpleType name="IDType">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="VENDOR_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="VENDOR_SITE_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="VENDOR_SITE_NUMBER"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="APPLICANT_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="AGMNT_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="SAMPLE_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="PROGRAM_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="QUOTE_ID"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="AAA_PARTY_ID"/>
    ...
    <xsd:enumeration value="PARTY_ID"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have two distinct kinds of element here:  Party identifiers (required) and identifiers which are not Party identifiers (optional).  Why have you chosen to give them the same name?  Consider the programmer who says "I want to have four variables; the first one should be an integer with a required value of 42, while the second and fourth should be strings which may or may not ever be initialized, and the third one should be a pointer.  Oh, and they all have to be called `x`.  Why won't the type system of this programming language let me do that?" In XSD, as in XML DTDs and most other schema languages for XML, constraints are associated with element names.  If you want distinct sets of constraints, use distinct element names.

The following XML is easier to validate in a schema, since it doesn't fight the tool.

```
<Identifiers>
  <partyID sourceSystem="ORACLE">38784313</partyID>
  <anyID sourceSystem="ORACLE">12345</anyID>
</Identifiers>
```

If you really prefer to write a hard-to-understand schema for hard-to-understand XML instead of a simple schema for simple XML, use XSD 1.1 and assertions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need this in the context of a migration project and therefore, unfortunately, the structure of the XML cannot be changed. The service consumers would otherwise need to adapt there requests, which is not desired.
Currently, this is set up in a way that the request is received by a gateway, which does the XSD check. It is then forwarded to an orchestration layer, which checks for the PARTY_ID. I did not like the idea of validating the request twice. That's why I was asking.
We will now most probably migrate the flow as is.